# ¿por que se me sube todo lo que tengo en el escritorio a github?

Tags: android-studio, git, github

el problema que tengo es que al trabajar con Android Studio, si quiero subir el proyecto a github, le doy donde dice VSS>import into version control>share proyect on github.(supuestamente aqui se crea el repositorio),pero le asigno nombre y despues no me sale la ventana donde aparece el proyecto que voy a subir(1a imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]), si no que de una vez sale uploading, y se tarda al rederor de 10min, para que me diga succefull, y cuando me voy a github, se me ha [introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec4cY.jpg)subido todo lo que tengo en el escritorio. espero me puedan ayudar, estaria muy agradecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Crea un repositorio nuevo en GitHub
Instala Git en Windows
Ve a la carpeta dónde está guardado tu proyecto de Android estudio y abre la terminal de Git ahí, e introduce los comandos que te ponen en GitHub

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "aquí tu mensaje"
git remote add (link de tu GitHub
git push
```

Comment: gracias por responder, de hecho estava investigando, y solo encontre informacion de como subirlo desde la consola de git, pero tambien se puede subir desde android studio sin usar la consola, el problema que no se porque se me sube todo el escritorio, pero a otros amigos se les sube normal, solo la carpeta de su proyecto.

Comment: @Ede4g el propio Android studio tiene una terminal, métete en ella y escribe dichos comandos

Comment: En realidad la pregunta de Ede4g es ¿porque se versiona todo ese contenido ? que no es en realidad un proyecto.

Comment: Creo que si, ese es el problema, no se me sube el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando.